# ASP.net login control design

Tags: asp.net, authentication, login-control

I've tried looking for this but can't find anything:

```
    <asp:Login id="Login1" runat="server" 
        TitleText=""
        CreateUserText="<br />Register a new account"
        CreateUserUrl="register.aspx" 
        PasswordRecoveryText = "Forgotten password?"
        PasswordRecoveryUrl="getPass.aspx" 
        UserNameLabelText="Username:<br />"
        OnLoggingIn="OnLoggingIn"
        FailureText="Your username/password is incorrect"
        FailureTextStyle-CssClass="errorMsg" HelpPageText="" TextBoxStyle-CssClass="formBox"

        OnLoginError="OnLoginError" >
        <LoginButtonStyle CssClass="searchBtn" />
    </asp:Login>
```

Given that code I would like to design the login box much  for createuserwizard, can this be done?  So I can layout all the elements exactly as I wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In design view of the page you can [convert login control to template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178340.aspx) and layout all elements as you wish.